# Map Custom Registration Fields to Wordpress User Roles

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

**How do I map these custom fields to the user profile?**

***Desired Functionality:***
if selected *'***Consumer***'* user role should be the '**Default- WordPress Role**'
if selected ***'Wholesale Buyer'*** user role should be **'Administrator'**

Here's - What I have so far?

```
function iconic_get_account_fields() {
    return apply_filters( 'iconic_account_fields', array(
        'user_url' => array(
            'type'        => 'select',
            'label'   => __( 'Select Field', 'iconic' ),
            'options' => array(
                '' => __( 'Select Customer', 'iconic' ),
                1  => __( 'Consumer', 'Consumer' ),
                2  => __( 'Wholesale Buyer', 'Wholesale' ),
            ),
            'required'    => true,
        ),
    ) );
}
/**
 * Add fields to the registration form and account area.
 */
function iconic_print_user_frontend_fields() {
    $fields = iconic_get_account_fields();

    foreach ( $fields as $key => $field_args ) {
        woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field_args );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'iconic_print_user_frontend_fields', 10 ); // register form
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'iconic_print_user_frontend_fields', 10 ); // my account
```

Comment: Note: I have additional users roles via a plugin. I am okay with the default WP roles map for now.

Comment: If I can ask, why do you want to modify the existing roles? Why not just add new roles and have their permissions the same as the original roles? Hope I am not missing the point here.

Comment: I haven't modified any existing user roles. I have merely created some additional roles with customized permissions and assigned them to the required users.
However, this has nothing to do with the question I asked.

Comment: I need to simply map the above code to the right user role during woocommerce registration.

Comment: The user meta fields are not dependant on the role they have but on the user object itself. Each User has many meta fields and one role. The issue is that you should be mapping the fields to a user and setting the correct role.